# Questions on Nodejs socket.io chat server with TONS of rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io, messaging

I'm trying to figure out how a chat app with lots of "rooms" would be implemented with nodejs and socket.io.

I know there are plenty of tutorials around for 1 room chats that run on 1 port, but my question is how would I transform something like that to support multiple chat rooms?

Would it require a different port per room? If so how would I get the server to sniff out open ports for this?.. or is there a better approach?

The target clients are native mobile sdks like iOS and android, so how would I get the server to open a room for a GET request?

Please excuse my noobness, I'm really trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I have to point you to [ActionHeroJS](http://www.actionherojs.com/), namely the built-in [chat server](http://www.actionherojs.com/docs/core/chat.html). This is accomplished with a single websocket port on the server, where each connection and each room is stored inside Redis. When a message is broadcast to a room, only those connections in that room get the message.

I might encourage you to try out the framework as an alternative to starting from scratch, but *definitely* look at the concepts as a way to manage a chat system at scale, beyond single-room-tutorials.